# Prove that triangle EDM is an isosceles right angel triangle

Tags: euclidean-geometry

[image]
In the diagram below triangle ABE is an isosceles right angle triangle and triangle ADC is an isosceles right angel triangle and M is in the middle of BC
prove that triangle EMD is an isosceles right angel triangle

Comment: Do you mean that $\triangle A\color{red}BE$ is an isosceles right triangles?

Comment: Median is for a triangle, not for a line segment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $L$ be a midpoint of $AB$, and $K$ be a midpoint of $AC$.

$EL=\frac{1}{2}AB=MK$

$ML=\frac{1}{2}AC=DK$

$\angle ELM=\angle BLM + 90^{\circ}=\angle MKC+90^{\circ}=\angle MKD$

By SAS congruence criterion
$\triangle ELM\equiv \triangle MKD$

From congruence we get $EM=DM$ and $\angle EML=\angle MDK$.

$\angle EMD=\angle EML+\angle LMK+\angle KMD=\angle MDK+ \angle MKC+\angle KMD=180^{\circ}-\angle CKD=90^{\circ}$